# Find the smallest possible length for the hypotenuse bounded by tangent line and normal line

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

I am given the following question, I have had a several gos on it but didnt manage to solve it at all.

**Question** givne the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}x,  x>0$$ given an arbitrary point on the graph bounded by the tangent and the normal lines to the point which together with the x-axis they form a right angle triangle, what is the smallest length that can the hypotenuse obtain?

[image: Here is what i think the triangle is supposed to look like]

**Hint** the answer is : $\frac {4}{3^\frac{3}4}$

Comment: (1) Consider an unknown point A = (a,1/a); (2) Find the equations of the tangent and normal lines to the curve at A; (3) In terms of a, find the x-intercepts of those lines; (4) In terms of a, find the length of the hypotenuse; (5) Use standard Calculus methods to find the minimum value.

Comment: @quasi thanks a lot of the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a long solution.....

Derivative of function is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$

Let us consider a point $x=p$ so $f(x)=1/p$

Now the equation of tangent line at $x=a$

$$y-\frac1p=\frac{-1}{p^2}(x-p)$$

Equation of normal line is 
$$y-\frac1p=p^2(x-p)$$

The $x$-intercepts of both lines are $$x=2p$$ and $$x=p-\frac{1}{p^3}$$
respectively.

Finding their distance to $p$ using distance formula gives two sides lengths.

Side $1$=$$\sqrt{p^2+\frac{1}{p^2}}$$
and 
Side $2$=$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{p^6}+\frac{1}{p^2}}$$
Since (By Pythagoras Theorem)
$$(Side \ 1)^2+(Side \ 2)^2=(Hypotenuse)^2$$

SO, hypotenuse $=$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{p^6}+\frac{2}{p^2}+p^2}$$
Computing derivative 
$$\frac{\frac{-6}{p^7}-\frac{4}{p^3}+2p}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{p^6}+\frac{2}{p^2}+p^2}}$$
and setting it to zero gives 
$$\frac{-6}{p^7}-\frac{4}{p^3}+2p=0$$
which equals $$p^8-2p^4-3=0$$
which when factorised gives

$$(p^4-3)(p^4+1)=0$$
which gives $p=\sqrt[4]3$
Putting this in
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{p^6}+\frac{2}{p^2}+p^2}$$
and simplifying gives...

$$Hypotenuse=\frac{4}{3^{\frac34}}$$

EDIT:

As noted in comments the hypotenuse is simply $$2p-p+\frac{1}{p^3}=p+\frac{1}{p^3}$$
After taking derivative and setting it to zero easily gives $$p=\sqrt[4]3$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @user35508: No need for the Pythagorean Theorem. The hypotenuse is the segment on the x-axis between the x-intercepts of the two lines, so the length of the hypotenuse is just the difference of the x-values of the two x-intercepts (bigger minus smaller).

Comment: Too complicated: the hypotenuse is the difference between $2p$ and $p-2/p^3$, namely $p+1/p^3$.

Comment: I noticed that now...Thanks ..I shall edit it but it's not complicated as you think....